# Wrong result from z3

Tags: optimization, solver, z3, satisfiability, sat-solvers

I'm trying to proof the following with Z3 SMT Solver: `((x*x) + x) = ((~x * ~x) + ~x)`.
This is correct, because of overflow semantic in the c programming language.

Now I have written the following smt-lib code:

```
(declare-fun a () Int)

(define-fun myadd ((x Int) (y Int)) Int (mod (+ x y) 4294967296) )
(define-fun mynot ((x Int))         Int (- 4294967295 (mod x 4294967296)) )
(define-fun mymul ((x Int) (y Int)) Int (mod (* x y) 4294967296) )

(define-fun myfun1 ((x Int)) Int (myadd (mynot x) (mymul (mynot x) (mynot x))) )
(define-fun myfun2 ((x Int)) Int (myadd x (mymul x x)) )

(simplify (myfun1 0))
(simplify (myfun2 0))

(assert (= (myfun1 a) (myfun2 a)))
(check-sat)
(exit)
```

The output from z3 is:

```
0
0
unsat
```

Now my question: Why is the result "unsat"? The simplify command in my code shows that it is possible to get a valid allocation so that myfun1 and myfun2 have the same result.

Is something wrong with my code or is this a bug in z3?

Please can anybody help me. Thx

Comment: If you're going to work with C-like integers and unless this is an exercise in manual encoding, I suggest you use bitvectors rather than mathematical integers.

Comment: Quick comment: this incorrect result is due to a bug in the Z3 formula preprocessor. It has been fixed, and the fix will be available in the next release. The bug affects benchmarks that use formulas of the form : `(mod (+ a b))` or `(mod (* a b))`.

Comment: @GManNickG: Good point, I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The incorrect result was due to a bug in the Z3 formula/expression preprocessor. The bug has been fixed, and is already part of the current release (v4.3.1). The bug affected benchmarks that use formulas of the form: `(mod (+ a b))` or `(mod (* a b))`.

We can retry the example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/plikF), and get the expected result.